# Is it possible to do User Interface A/B testing with Algolia?

Tags: algolia

We are using Algolia for searching in our React app. Now we would like to introduce A/B testing for our application. We want to test some different designs, user interfaces with different user target groups. As far as I see from the documentation of Algolia, A/B testing is possible using different indices for search. But is it possible to do design A/B testing with Algolia?